# Angular Animation Javascript VS CSS.

Tags: angularjs, animation

I saw an animation  directive that said animations are done best with javascript. Is this the case?

I am using Angular 1.3 and  want  a plug and play  solution for animation. Can you explain the difference in the JS vs CSS question and direct me to a source to get it implemented FAST?

Backstory
I have an APP I want to launch tomorrow. I wrote it in Angular quickly but am having trouble with animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna animate angular directives ng-show/hide, ng-repeat, etc then css animations are the way to go. All you do is add some classes to you css file with animations and off you go as long as you have included the NgAnimate as a dependency.

If you wanna implement your own directive animations then JS is the way using $animate service.

Check out [year of moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-ngshow-and-ng-hide), Matias does a great job of showing them.